# Using wget or curl with a changing name file

Tags: regex, flash, cmd, filenames, wget

First of all please excuse my bad english, I'll try to get understandable.

I'm using a batch file (Windows, cmd.exe) to retrieve and silently install Adobe Flash on my computer.
The batch works well, but I have a problem when there is a major version change on Adobe servers.
Here is the command line batch:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions

md c:\temp\flash
pushd c:\temp\flash

wget -nH --cut-dirs=5 -r --timestamping http://download.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/licensing/win/install_flash_player_15_plugin.exe
wget -nH --cut-dirs=5 -r --timestamping http://download.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/licensing/win/install_flash_player_15_active_x.exe

echo Closing browsers
pause
taskkill /f -im firefox.exe -im iexplore.exe

install_flash_player_15_plugin.exe -install -au 2
install_flash_player_15_active_x.exe -install -au 2

popd

setlocal disableextensions
pause
```

When Flash is upgraded to the next version, the filename changes from  `install_flash_player_15_active_x.exe`
to 
`install_flash_player_16_active_x.exe` 
and the batch must be manually corrected or else it is stuck with an old version.

Is there any way to replace the version number with wildcards or some regular expression in order to have wget to retrieve the latest file when its name change ?
Or at least, is there any Windows compatible command line tool which parses the file names on a server, find the latest and passes it as a variable for wget (or cURL) ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need Regular Expressions to get the current version of flash for IE and Firefox. Just change the URLs to

For Firefox: http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/current/support/install_flash_player.exe
For IE: http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/current/support/install_flash_player_ax.exe

```
wget -nH --cut-dirs=5 -r --timestamping http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/current/support/install_flash_player.exe
wget -nH --cut-dirs=5 -r --timestamping http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/current/support/install_flash_player_ax.exe
```